# дополнить часть строки через регулярку

Tags: php

Задача звучит так:
Напишите скрипт, который найдёт в строке все даты и заменит их на дату с днем недели

```
<?php
$str = 'Давайте устроим встречу 20.05.2022 и потом ещё одну 12.06.2022';
// ЗДЕСЬ НУЖЕН КОД
echo $str; // Давайте устроим встречу 20.05.2022 (пт) и потом ещё одну 12.06.2022 (вс).
```

Ее я выполнил так:

```
<?php

$str = 'Давайте устроим встречу 20.05.2029 и потом ещё одну 09.06.2022';

$n = preg_match_all('/\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}/', $str, $matches);

$new = [];

foreach ($matches as $date => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $new[] = $value.' '.date("D", strtotime($value));
    }
}

str_replace($matches, $new, $str);
echo $str;
```

Не работает. В чем косяк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этих целей оптимально будет подходить `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback("/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/", function($match){
                 $day = date("D", strtotime($match[0]));
                 return "{$match[0]} ($day)";
            }, $str);
```

хотя с другой стороны, можно еще и убедиться что у нас представлена действительно дата, например, используя `checkdate`.

```
$result = preg_replace_callback("/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/", function($match){
                list($full, $d, $m, $y) = $match;

                if(!checkdate($m, $d, $y)) return $full;

                $day = date("D", mktime(0,0,0, $m,$d,$y));
                return "$full ($day)";
            }, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = 'Давайте устроим встречу 20.05.2029 и потом ещё одну 09.06.2022';

preg_match_all('/\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}/', $str, $matches);

$search = [];
$replace = [];

foreach ($matches as $date => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $search[] = $value;
            $replace[] = $value.' '.date("D", strtotime($value));
    }
}

$str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace($matches, $new, $str);
```

Answer (score -1):

str_replace - эта функция возвращает строку или массив с замененными значениями(Не меняет исходную).